# Why can I not deserialize YAML into a record?

Tags: c#, yaml, record, yamldotnet

I am using YamlDotNet and I wanted to use records for my deserialized YAML. However, I get an error like this when I try to do so:

```
Unhandled exception. (Line: 2, Col: 3, Idx: 9) - (Line: 2, Col: 3, Idx: 9): Exception during deserialization
```

From further experimentation, I discovered record structs, which work completely fine. Regular structs work and so do classes with get and init properties. Clearly I do not know much about records in C#. Out of curiosity, does anybody know what it is about records that prevents them from being deserialized to by YamlDotNet?

Comment: Do you have any detailed exception messages (perhaps in the `InnerException`)?

Comment: Records don't have settable properties but can only be initialized through a constructor call -- which requires that data is matched positionally, which is beyond the capabilities of most libraries.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You can have records with settable properties just fine

Comment: @canton7: OK, my bad -- class records don't have settable properties *by default*, when declared in the usual way. (Whereas record structs *do* if not explicitly declared `readonly`, which explains the difference.)

Comment: @canton7 I do get something like `System.MissingMethodException : Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'RecordType'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.`

Comment: And init-only properties can be set through reflection (which was intentional, so as not to break serializers)

Comment: @BlueStaggo Your record needs to have a parameterless constructor

Comment: My best guess is that the deserializer tries to create a class through a default constructor then it sets the properties. I guess this cannot be done with records.

Comment: @BlueStaggo You can have a record with a parameterless constructor, e.g. [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+tJQCYAIBKAFAJYB2ALrgBoCUAsAFADejubuAAgMwGE24hc5ABbEAzoS78muAL6NZQA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr you'll need a simple workaround, because it's not supported out-of-the-box, see https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/issues/571**

You need to have paremeter-less (0-arg) constructor in your `record` for current (circa 13.x) YamlDotNet versions to be able to deserialize. That c-tor will be used solely to create the record in its pre-deserialization state, so you can provide it with normally invalid/unwanted values, like `null` or other defaults. YamlDotNet will then use "magical" (reflection-based) setting methods anyway, and you can check for those invalid/unwanted values later to verify if the deserialized data actually has everything you need to have a complete record.

E.g.

```
public record Config(
    string someParam,
    string otherParam,
    string yetAnotherParam
) {
    public Config() : this(null, null, null) {
    }

    public void Validate() {
        if (someParam == null || otherParam == null || yetAnotherParam == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("not all required fields were deserialized properly", (Exception) null);
        }
    }

}
```

will work just fine, and then you can just call `Validate()` straight after deserialization if you want (yes, it's not as effective as library-level support for this, but still).

*Alternatively* (although I don't really advise to do it), you can e.g.:

- deserialize YAML to `object` using YamlDotNet,
- serialize that `object` to JSON via `System.Text.Json`,
- and finally deserialize that JSON to your target record (via `System.Text.Json` as well)

It's both terrible for performance and would require even more obfuscation of the logic in code, but at least can be hidden in a helper method etc.